# Clarification on Regular expression Extractor and CSV Data set config

Tags: jmeter

**Question 1 )** I am reading user credentials from a CSV file and trying to simulate concurrent 3 user login scenario like below.

My csv file data is like below, each in a new row. The problem now im facing is all requests are useing credential_001 if I use Attached ( thread group Settings .JPG) thread group settings. but if I make it to loop count 3, then it sends login requests for 3 users. What is wrong in my approach. please advice

```
credential_001

credential_002

credential_003
```

[http://i.imgur.com/FNXTMvA.jpg][1]

**Question 2 )** When I capture 3 session tokens in first authentication cycle, I wand to use that 3 requests in next 3 requests. How can I do this ? is it posible to do like this. with my current approach it is always send the session token of first authentication in later http samplers.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/bizIp.jpg

below is the regular exp extra im using , and Im using ${SessionGuid} in later http sampler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

Consider switching to [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function as CSV Data Set config switches to next row on next **iteration**, not on next thread. Example CSVRead configuration will look like:

```
${__CSVRead(/path/to/file/with/credentials.csv,0)
```

**Question 2**

Consider using [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function together with `${SessionGuid}` variable, this way you'll be able to get

```
SessionGuid1 for the first thread
SessionGuid2 for the second thread
```

You can evaluate SessionGuid1, SessionGuid2, etc. variables using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function as follows:

```
${__V(SessionGuid${__threadNum})}
```

For extended information on above and more functions check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series.